# OpenGL Compute Shader vs Fragment Shader device support

Tags: java, libgdx, opengl-es, fragment-shader, compute-shader

I have a game with massively parallelizable logic, which I intend to write calculate on the GPU (Java/LibGDX).

I am planning to implement a logic for it through a fragment shader, instead of a compute shader because I have the intuition that Fragment shaders supported on more devices, than compute shaders.

Is this even true? Given all other variables eliminated, are fragment shaders available on more devices, than compute shaders? Or in openGLES(desktop, android, ios) compute shaders are always available anyway?

What restrictions are in effect here?

Comment: Reading and writing floating point pixel data requires to have OpenGLES3 anyway, so maybe by openGLES 3 compute shaders are standard anyway?

Comment: As for OpenGL ES 3:
 in android https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html most devices are already in GLES3 
But in ios: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html 
it seems the entire openGLES system is deprecated